# Help determining angle

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, polar-coordinates

Let $R$ be the triangle defined by $−x\tan(\theta) \le  y \le x\tan(\theta)$ and $x \le 1$ where theta is an acute angle.  Sketch the triangle and calculate

\begin{equation*}
\iint_R(x^2+y^2)\mathrm dA
\end{equation*}

using polar coordinates.

I got $r=\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}=\sec(\theta)$ but I am stuck on how to get the angle to solve this question... :/

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify? What is $-x\tan{\theta}$?

Comment: what do you mean?? y≤xtan(θ) and y>=-xtan(θ)

Comment: Don't quite understand which angle are you looking for....

Comment: there's only 1 angle which is theta for y=xtan(θ)

Comment: or the region where theta applies in this case

Comment: I suggest that you do not use polar coordinate to calculate. You are integrating over a triagnle, so it is easier to use just $x-y$ coordinate.

Comment: the problem is i have to use polar co-ord to calculate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The triangle's angles are located at $(0,0)$, $(1,\tan\theta)$ and $(-1,\tan\theta)$. Using polar coordinates we have to integrate for a given angle $\theta'$ from the radius $0$ to $r=\sqrt{1^2+\tan^2\theta}=\sec\theta$. This gives
$$I=\iint_R(x^2+y^2)\mathrm dA=\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}\mathrm d\theta'\int_0^{\sec\theta'}r^2\,r\mathrm dr=\frac14\int_{-\theta}^\theta\sec^4\theta'\,\mathrm d\theta'.$$
The result of this integral is, setting $t=\tan\theta'$
$$I=\frac14\;2\times\int_0^{\tan\theta}(1+t^2)\mathrm dt=\frac12\left(\tan\theta+\frac13\tan^3\theta\right).$$

**Note added in edit** (cartesian coordinates)
$$\begin{split}
I&=\int_0^1\mathrm dx\int_{-x\tan\theta}^{x\tan\theta}(x^2+y^2)\mathrm dy\\
&=\int_0^1\mathrm dx\left[x^2y+\frac13y^3\right]_{y=-x\tan\theta}^{y=x\tan\theta}\\
&=2\int_0^1\mathrm dx\left(x^3\tan\theta+\frac13x^3\tan^3\theta\right)\\
&=2\left(\tan\theta+\frac13\tan^3\theta\right)\int_0^1x^3\mathrm dx\\
&=2\left(\tan\theta+\frac13\tan^3\theta\right)\left[\frac{x^4}4\right]_{0}^1\\&=\frac12\left(\tan\theta+\frac13\tan^3\theta\right).\end{split}$$

Comment: I dont really get the second section how you get tanθ and 0 on the limits/range (that thing on the integral sign) and how its (1+t^2) not (1+t^2)^2

Comment: 1) The range: the function is even so $\int_{-\theta}^\theta=2\int_0^\theta$. 2) As $t=\tan\theta'$ we have $\mathrm dt=\sec^2\theta'\,\mathrm d\theta'$.  Use $\sec^2\theta'=1+t^2$ to get the expression.

Comment: sorry to keep bothering you but how does 2∫θ 0 turn into 2∫tanθ 0

Comment: The change of variable $t=\tan \theta$ modifies the boundaries of the integral. You should probably learn more about it. It's called [integration by substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution).

Comment: i completely forgot about that... i feel so stupid now... anyway thanks